# How To add CLI Workspace and Other Files to Existing Angular 5 project?

Tags: npm, migration, angular-cli, package.json, angular8

### The Problem

On an existing Angular 5x application, I want to upgrade to Angular v8x and take advantage of all the sexy things, including `ng generate component`. I successfully modified the code to satisfy v8, and changed the npm packages correctly; the app runs (whoo-hoo!). Now, I can't get the Angular cli to work because of missing files like `angular.json`.

### Things I've tried

#### Using `ng new`

`ng new` will create the project files I need, but I didn't want to overwrite my existing code, e.g. `app.module.ts`, so I ran

`ng new my-app --directory [existing source directory of my app]`

That overwrote many files, `package.json`, `app.module.ts`,etc, so I ran int again as:

`ng new revenue --directory=./ --create-application=false --force`

A lot of files were preserved, but `package.json` was not.

### The Goal

1. Have my now upgraded app, running Angular v8, able to run fun things like `ng serve`
2. Not have to re-write `package.json`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to Angular 8 **should** modify package.json.

People typically use `ng update` to do this ([link](https://www.techiediaries.com/updating-angular-cli-projects/)).

> **Updating Configuration Files**
>
> There are many differences between Angular 4|5 and Angular 6 such as
>
> - Angular 6 uses `angular.json` instead of `angular-cli.json`.
> - Different versions of dependencies in `package.json` etc.
>
> You can update different configuration files automatically by running the following command from the project's root folder:
>
> `ng update @angular/cli`

---

> What is the `ng update` Command?
>
> `Ng update` is a command available in Angular CLI which is used to update your application and its dependencies. You can use it to update all packages in the `package.json` file via the `--all` option that could take `true` or `false` or specific versions via the `--packages option`. You can see all the available commands from the official docs.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a brand-new application with `ng new my-app`, then copying over the files from the existing app. After modifying the code to work with Angular 8, using `HttpClient`, for example, the app successfully ran. I think I had to do it this way because of the fundamental changes to the project meta files. Hopefully, future upgrades won't be so challenging.